# LUUP Code VeraLite Weather and LED Strip Fibaro

Tags: lua

I'm trying to set up a scene for veralite. I want the LEDs to change color depending to the temperature. In the following LUUP code, Device ID 12 is the CurrentTemperature ; R G B and W are respectively 18, 17, 19 and 20.

I would like to know why my code doesn't work.
Thank you so much for your help.

```
local lul_temp = luup.variable_get("urn:upnp-org:serviceId:TemperatureSensor1","CurrentTemperature", 12)
local R = 18 -- RGB Red, device ID
local G = 17 -- RGB Green, device ID
local B = 19 -- RGB Blue, device ID
local W = 20 -- RGB White, device ID

local Colours = { 
    [32] = {Temp=32, R=32, G=32, B=32, W=0, Name='32'},
    [33] = {Temp=33, R=33, G=33, B=33, W=0, Name='33'},
    [34] = {Temp=34, R=34, G=34, B=34, W=0, Name='34'},
    ...
    [72] = {Temp=72, R=72, G=72, B=72, W=0, Name='72'}
}

local v = Colours[tonumber(lul_temp)] -- look up the table value using index 


if (tonumber(lul_temp) > 31) then
    luup.call_action("urn:upnp-org:serviceId:Dimming1", "SetLoadLevelTarget", {newLoadlevelTarget = v.R, R) -- RGB Red
    luup.call_action("urn:upnp-org:serviceId:Dimming1", "SetLoadLevelTarget", {newLoadlevelTarget = v.G, G) -- RGB Green
    luup.call_action("urn:upnp-org:serviceId:Dimming1", "SetLoadLevelTarget", {newLoadlevelTarget = v.B, B) -- RGB Blue
    luup.call_action("urn:upnp-org:serviceId:Dimming1", "SetLoadLevelTarget", {newLoadlevelTarget = v.W, W) -- RGB White
end
```

Comment: You didn't close the tabular argument in `luup.call_action`s.

Comment: Add specifically how it *doesn't work*.

Comment: @hjpotter92 do i have to put a comma after each luup.call.action ? sorry, i'm a noob in LUUP

Comment: OK, In case someone has the same issue, the the correct markdown is 
    `luup.call_action("urn:upnp-org:serviceId:Dimming1", "SetLoadLevelTarget", {newLoadlevelTarget = v.W}, W)`